# Entering a number in scientific noation in Android apps

Tags: android

I want to be able to use scientific notation in my app for the following statement...

```
float wc = Float.parseFloat(editText3.getText().toString());
```

which becomes a prompt for a numeric input.  This works as it is, and I can input 2000 but not 2e3.

Comment: That ought to work. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
Double.valueOf("9.18E+09").longValue()
```

or

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("9.18E+09");
long val = bd.longValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look at the string and make the changes yourself.

I suggest something like this:

```
String str = editText3.getText().toString();
double fValue;
if (str.contains("e")) {
    String[] parts = str.split("e");
    double part1 = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
    double part2 = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
    fValue = part1 * Math.pow(10, part2);
} else {
    fValue = Double.parseDouble(str);
}
```

Note that this is not tested, but I think it will work fine.

Comment: @Waza_Be good catch, feel pretty dumb about that one. Edit made.